# floating action button not showing image

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button

I've added xml code to have a floating action button on my screen (no functionality right now but will) but when I go onto the design view of xml, instead of showing the email icon image, it shows just text like 'floating action button': ' [image]

Could someone explain what I've done wrong?

```
the code I use:

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>
```

Comment: post your xml layout code

Comment: build the project

Comment: Have u added  design support lib   `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'` for `FloatingActionButton`

Comment: Thanks @NileshRathod, that worked!

Comment: Where can I find all the icons that android already has in the system? Like I am using the mail one, are there others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the correct library is not added. Try adding design library

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```