# Floating Action Button is not showing an image in Android?

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button, material-components-android

As title says, I don't know how to fix this issue. I read this **[problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739465/floating-action-button-not-showing-image)** but that was in 2018, I'm not very familiar with all those libraries and dependencies how it all works. But judging from my Declared Dependencies, from Android Studio, this is what I got:

[image]

I would like to add some kind of "Attach document" icon/image to the FAB. I tried to do this by adding a `New Vector` asset, but images do not appear in my drawable folder. How can I add a nice icon/image to my project, and set it to a FAB?

Here is XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:icon="@drawable/attache_file">

    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>
```

Comment: say android:src instead on android:icon

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution, just add this below statement inside dimens.xml

`<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>`

And must need to add **app:tint="@null"** inside your FAB design xml

````
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomBar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
        app:tint="@null" />```

Happy to help :)
````

Answer (score 3):

To use the `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton` add the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Then use the **`app:srcCompat`** attribute:

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/..."
      .../>
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button) you have to use `android:src="@drawable/attache_file"`

Comment: Damn, I miss that, 3h just wasted :) Thanks, it works